# Python sqlite3 build where part with dynamic placeholders

Tags: python, sqlite, placeholder

I have a form which 4 input fields, when clicking the submit button, I'm fetching results from the database based on those 4 inputs. I'm not forcing the user to enter any input, so I could get all blank inputs or part of them empty. The more inputs the user fills, the results from the database will be more precise.

My problem is how to build the where part of the query dynamically using only the place holders which are populated. here is my query. This way if one of the inputs are blank, the query will not fetch anything while my intention is the opposite: if the input is blank, do not take into account while querying the database.

```
cursor.execute('''
        SELECT name, id, gender, age, address, phones, mails, gender, age, hair_color                     
        FROM persons
        WHERE 
           name = ? AND            
           id = ? AND 
           gender = ? AND 
           age = ? 
        ''', (name_input, id_input, gender_input, age_input))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create the WHERE clause dynamically:

```
sql = "SELECT ... WHERE 1"
parameters = []
if name_input != "":
    sql += " AND name = ?"
    parameters += [name_input]
if id_input != "":
    sql += " AND id = ?"
    parameters += [id_input]
...
```

Alternatively, rewrite the WHERE clause so that empty values are ignored:

```sql
SELECT ... WHERE (name = ?1 OR ?1 = '') AND (id = ?2 OR ?2 = '') AND ...
```

([`?n` specifies the n-th parameter](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam).)